# Дефис или тире лучше?

Tags: тире, дефис

«Парки-памятники садово-паркового искусства». Дефис или тире....?  Памятник садово-паркового искусства, распространенное приложение....Вроде как тире просится....

Comment: Где видится тире? Вообще, это название или часть фразы?

Comment: «Реконструируются парки-памятники садово-паркового искусства»....   «Садово-паркового искусства» примыкает к памятнику...Если бы не было, то писалось бы с дефисом, очевидно?....

Comment: "Реконструируются парки – памятники садово-паркового искусства..."   Хорошо было бы редактировать предложение. Замечания такие: повтор парки – паркового;  стечение согласных "п";  тире рядом с дефисом. Также:  обособление приложения  с помощью тире обычно делается в конце предложения (так лучше смотрится присоединительная конструкция).  Тогда желательно видеть всё предложение.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: 
*«Парки — памятники садово-паркового искусства».*

Необходимо тире  потому, что приложение многословное:

> § 154. В следующих случаях вместо дефиса должен употребляться знак
> тире.
>
> 1. В сочетаниях с приложением, если одна из частей содержит пробел.
>
>    ...
>    Примеры с неоднословными приложениями:
>
>    ```
>    творчество поэтов — современников Пушкина; статьи о Горьком — общественном деятеле, о Маршаке — переводчике Шекспира; печальная судьба дома — памятника архитектуры; обратиться к директору — художественному руководителю; среди стран — участников переговоров. Ср. поэты-современники, Горький-писатель, Маршак-переводчик, дом-памятник, директор-распорядитель.
>    ```
>
> *[[Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации полный академический
> справочник, редактор В. В. Лопатин](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp154.php)]*

Answer (score 0):

1. Реконструируются парки-памятники — произведения садово-паркового искусства.
2. Реконструируются ландшафтные памятники — произведения садово-паркового искусства.
3. Реконструируются ландшафтные произведения — памятники садово-паркового искусства.